# problema con look for i in range(0,len(data)):

Tags: python, pdf, canvas, reportlab

tengo este SCRIPT que toma los datos de la base de datos e imprime dentro del PDF pero no logro colocar correctamente el look for i in range(0,len(data)):

> Librerias utilizadas

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, A4
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Table, TableStyle, PageBreak, Frame
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.units import cm

headers=[["Item", "Cantidad","Producto","Precio","Neto","%","Itbis","Total"]]
        query = ("SELECT referencia, cantidad, producto, precio , neto , porciento , itbis , total  from orden_compra ")
        self.run_query(query)
        tabla_mostrar = self.cursor.fetchall()
        data =[]
        for row in tabla_mostrar:
            
            data_tabla =[row[0],row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7]]
            headers.append(data_tabla)
            data.append(row)
```

> Si muevo el loop intentando evitar que copie los headers aun asi
> hereda el estilo de linea negra que hereda THEADER, que no puedo sacar del loop debido a que el estilo es parte de la fila del loop, alguna idea?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
theader = Table([headers[0]], colWidths=[30,50,220,55,50,30,50,55])#columnas del titulo
        tstyle = TableStyle([("GRID",(0,0),(0,0),1,colors.white),
                    ('LINEABOVE', (0,0), (-1,0), 2, colors.black)])#lineas
                        #("FONT",(0,0),(-1,-1),"Arial",12)])


        theader.setStyle(tstyle)
        flow_obj.append(theader)
        for i in range(0,len(data)):
            trow =  Table([data[i]], colWidths=[30,50,220,55,50,30,50,55])#fila de los datos
            trow.setStyle(tstyle)#estilo de la fila Theader trow
            flow_obj.append(trow)#crea las fila
        frame =Frame(30,320,550,300, showBoundary=1)#x30 =mueve x2=550ancha 
        frame.addFromList(flow_obj,pdf) #frame = cuadro negro quien es showBoundary
        pdf.showPage()
        pdf.save()
```

Comment: Estás metiendo en `headers` los datos de las filas, por eso se duplica. Por favor, intenta corregir la identación del código y, si es posible, añade contexto para que podamos probarlo (se supone que estás definiendo algún método de clase que no vemos).

Comment: Saludos, es un metodo que llama a la TABLA de una base de datos en SQL, e imprime esos datos dentro de un PDF. pues le agregare las librerias que llame. a ver si queda mas claro.

Comment: por que no usas pandas para manipular la data?

Comment: no se utilizarlo, solo vi mucha info de reportlab con canvas y pues alli intento formatear mi pdf.

Comment: @wally Yo estoy viendo un `self.run_query()` que no tengo ni idea de qué hace ahí. Interpreto que es parte de un método que no veo porque falta código. Más que explicar lo que hace tu código, lo conveniente es que sea un código que podamos probar para ver dónde concretamente tienes el problema. Quizás te oriente la ayuda sobre [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Y cuida la identación, conviene que la corrijas.

Comment: @ChemaCortes eso es una llamada a la base de datos SQLITE para cargar la tabla y no repetir dicho codigo alli 2 veces, por eso tiene self. significa que los datos se encuentran en otra parte. So lo q hago alli es basicamente llamar a todos los HEADERS de la tabla orden de compra. y la segunda imagen es la que carga los datos de la tabla como puedes ver en la foto.